# How can i download a file using QNetworkAccessManager as a QT DLL function?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create a QT DLL to use it in an InnoSetup installer (InnoSetup is written in Delphi Pascal).

This DLL should have a function to download a file from the internet when called from InnoSetup.

The InnoSetup call is made like this:

```
procedure downloadFile();
  external '_ZN9testClass10doDownloadEv@files:classTest.dll stdcall delayload';
```

and then I call it using this:

```
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  ExtractTemporaryFile('classTest.dll');
  downloadFile();
end;
```

I've tried this with a simple function in my DLL and it's working. Here is the test function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void testClass::testFunction()
{
    QFile file("output.txt");
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << "Function call is working!";
    file.close();
}
```

Now, i've tried to implement in my DLL a function that will download a file using QNetworkAccessManager and QThreads. Sadly, this doesn't work for some reason that is beyond me.

Here is my DLL code:

```
-- TESTDLL.H --

#ifndef TESTDLL_H
#define TESTDLL_H

#include <QtCore>

#include "testdll_global.h"
#include "libs/downloader.h"

class TESTCLASS_EXPORT testClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    void doDownload();
    void handleResults();
  public slots:
  private:
};

#endif // TESTDLL_H


-- TESTDLL_GLOBAL.H --

#ifndef TESTDLL_GLOBAL_H
#define TESTDLL_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(TESTCLASS_LIBRARY)
#  define TESTCLASS_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define TESTCLASS_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // TESTDLL_GLOBAL_H


-- TESTDLL.CPP --

#include "testdll.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void testClass::doDownload()
{
     downloadWorker *ts_testDownloadWorker = new downloadWorker(this);
     connect(ts_testDownloadWorker, &downloadWorker::finished, ts_testDownloadWorker, &QObject::deleteLater);
     connect(ts_testDownloadWorker, &downloadWorker::resultReady, this, &testClass::handleResults);
     ts_testDownloadWorker->Execute();
}

void testClass::handleResults()
{
    QFile file("result.txt");
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << "Passed!";
    file.close();
}


-- DOWNLOADER.H --

#ifndef DOWNLOADER_H
#define DOWNLOADER_H

#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QDebug>

class downloadWorker : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
 signals:
    void resultReady(const QString &s);

 public:
    downloadWorker(QObject *parent);
    ~downloadWorker();
    void Execute();
    void saveToDisk(QString fileName, QByteArray content);

 protected:
    void run();

 private:
    bool m_abort;
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkMgr;
    QNetworkReply *replyNetworkSmall;

  public slots:
    void startDownload (QString url, QString fileName);
    QByteArray prepareDownload(QString &url);
    void downloadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);
    void replyNetworkSmallError();
};

#endif // DOWNLOADER_H


-- DOWNLOADER.CPP --

#include "downloader.h"

downloadWorker::downloadWorker(QObject *parent)
    : QThread(parent)
{
    m_abort = false;
}

downloadWorker::~downloadWorker()
{
   m_abort = true;
   wait();
}

void downloadWorker::Execute()
{
    m_abort = false;
    start();
}

void downloadWorker::run()
{
    QString result;

    startDownload("http://www.google.com", "download.txt");
    exec();

    emit resultReady(result);
}

void downloadWorker::startDownload (QString url, QString fileName)
{
    QByteArray downloadUrl = prepareDownload(url);
    saveToDisk(fileName, downloadUrl);
}

QByteArray downloadWorker::prepareDownload(QString &url)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkMgr = new QNetworkAccessManager;
    connect(networkMgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(downloadFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute, true);
    request.setUrl(url);
    replyNetworkSmall = networkMgr->get(request);
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(replyNetworkSmall, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(replyNetworkSmall, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
                this, SLOT(replyNetworkSmallError()));
    loop.exec();

    QByteArray bts = replyNetworkSmall->readAll();
    return bts;
}

void downloadWorker::saveToDisk(QString fileName, QByteArray content)
{
    QFile mfile(fileName);

    if (!mfile.open(QFile::ReadWrite))
        {
            mfile.close();
            QFile::remove(fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            mfile.write(content);
            mfile.flush();
            mfile.close();
        }
}

void downloadWorker::downloadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    reply->deleteLater();
    this->exit();
}

void downloadWorker::replyNetworkSmallError()
{
    if(replyNetworkSmall->error())
    {
        //errorSmallDownload(replyNetworkSmall->errorString());
        //downloadError = true;
    }
    replyNetworkSmall->deleteLater();
}


-- TESTDLL.pro --

QT -= gui
QT += network

TEMPLATE = lib
DEFINES += TESTCLASS_LIBRARY

CONFIG += c++11 dll

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    testdll.cpp \
    libs\downloader.cpp

HEADERS += \
    testdll_global.h \
    testdll.h \
    libs\downloader.h

QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,--output-def,testdll.def

# Default rules for deployment.
unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
}
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

If I try to call doDownload function, no file is downloaded, it's like there's no exec loop in my dll to actually do the job. But, if I turn this code into an app and use a main with exect, the file is downloading.

What else can I do to the above code to actually manage to download a file? Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance guys!

PS: I'm fully aware InnoSetup has his own file downloader function implemented. But, i want to use the download function from my own DLL ;)

**SOLUTION**

Here is the solution to my problem, based on @MSalters's answer:

```
-- TESTDLL.H --

#ifndef TESTDLL_H
#define TESTDLL_H

#include <QtCore>

#include "testdll_global.h"
#include "libs/downloader.h"

class testClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    void doDownload();
    void handleResults();
  public slots:
  private:
};

#endif // TESTDLL_H


-- TESTDLL.CPP --

#include "testdll.h"

namespace QCoreAppDLL
{
    static int argc = 1;
    static char * argv[] = {(char *)"testdll.cpp", nullptr};
    static QCoreApplication * pApp = nullptr;
}

extern "C" TESTCLASS_EXPORT void initDLL()
{
    if (!QCoreApplication::instance())
    {
        QCoreAppDLL::pApp = new QCoreApplication(QCoreAppDLL::argc, QCoreAppDLL::argv);

        testClass w;
        w.doDownload();

        QCoreAppDLL::pApp->exec();
    }
}

void testClass::doDownload()
{
     downloadWorker *ts_testDownloadWorker = new downloadWorker(this);
     connect(ts_testDownloadWorker, &downloadWorker::finished, ts_testDownloadWorker, &QObject::deleteLater);
     connect(ts_testDownloadWorker, &downloadWorker::resultReady, this, &testClass::handleResults);
     ts_testDownloadWorker->Execute();
}

void testClass::handleResults()
{
    if (QCoreAppDLL::pApp)
        QCoreAppDLL::pApp->quit();
}
```

Comment: "external '_ZN9testClass10doDownloadEv". You may want to read up on `extern "C"`. C has no classes, or class functions, so you're not going to get a nice C name for `testClass::testFunction`.

Comment: Correct, ill do that after i'll fix the main problem of my dll, cheers!

Comment: "(char *)"testdll.cpp" That looks quite dangerous. It's not unheard of for a command-line parser to remove arguments that it handled, which works when `argv` is writeable (as it usually is).

Comment: Wanted to supress the "warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *'" warning. Is there another way to supress it?

Comment: Sort of off topic, but for the record, there is an existing plugin for Inno Setup to download files through HTTP(S): https://mitrichsoftware.wordpress.com/inno-setup-tools/inno-download-plugin/

Comment: Thanks but i've already stated in my initial post that i know about specific Inno download plugins. I just wanted to make it work from QT for personal use without depending on extra libraries ;)

Comment: This is fine! Just thinking of people searching for such a solution in the future and arriving here ;-)

Comment: @JohnnyUSA: You have only hidden the warning, but the problem is still there. Just add an extra `char argv0[] = "testdll.cpp";`.

Comment: @MSalters I understand. Thanks! Recently by using my dll i noticed something not working properly with the function called within QCoreApplication. Thing is, it doesnt properly close when used so i can't reuse it because QCoreAPP doesnt exit on handleResults. I've tried to use delete QCoreAppDLL::pApp instead of  QCoreAppDLL:pApp->quit(); but this is closing the host application also. Do i need to spawn QCoreAppDLL:pApp in a Thread so i can use the delete option without closing the host also? Or how do i properly close QCoreApp after my function is finished?

Comment: @JohnnyUSA: good question - ask it! (I don't think  there is an existing question yet)

Comment: @MSalters ,thanks, i just did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66384153/how-can-i-properly-close-qcoreapplication-in-an-qt-dll-that-is-using-qtnetwork-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, in an ordinary Qt app, this will work. That's because your `QApplication` object handles the `QCoreApplication::notify` function. In your DLL, you don't need the full `QApplication` but you still need at least a `QCoreApplication`

Comment: Thanks, i found a way to reimplement what you've suggested and it's working now. Posted the fixed code also others can benefit from it.